# Plating via without chemicals

Tags: pcb, via, manufacturing, plating

In my lab we can mill and drill double sided PCBs. Holes are not plated. To create a via we usually use little copper rivets. Electroplating is out of the question because we don’t do any chemicals here.
PCBs that we make here are one-offs. No production but just prototyping.

Has anybody ever tried a different ways to create a via other than the two options above?
Maybe fill it with solder paste and reflow? Maybe even other ways?

Comment: I have used silver epoxy that is sucked through the vias using a vacuum system and cured. Not particularly reliable, and the epoxy has a limited shelf life.

Comment: You can just stick a thin wire through and solder on both sides. Copper rivet sounds like most convenient though.

Comment: What is it about solder paste that makes it less of a chemical than a metal salt solution? Anyway riveting seems like a quick, yet sturdy solution already.

Comment: @tobalt I think it’s because solder paste is in a syringe, you don’t touch or spill it easily and you’ll not end up with waist residu I guess? With electroplating solution you will be left with the remaining solution and the remaining of the rinsing baths. At least that’s what I was told.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few ways to do this, although the copper rivet seems like the best option which I have actually not seen before.

1. Just fill the via with solder. You could hand solder it or reflow solder it.
2. Fill the via with a wire and solder on both sides.
3. Fill the via with conductive epoxy.

You will want to check continuity on both sides of the via after filling it to make sure it worked correctly. It can be a bit tricky to get right, especially if you have more than 20 vias you're trying to fill.

Comment: Ohhh, you could  peen a small piece of wire solder into the hole and then just melt it along with everything else.

Comment: @DKNguyen That's what I do when I need a two-layer proto, carve out traces with a utility blade then drill holes and fill with wire. Nothing too precise, though I do have some wire and drill sets that yield a tight fit; but I wouldn't trust a hand-riveted joint electrically, I always solder over it, which does leave the board a bit non-flat. Fine for proto work.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference I’ll answer my own question base on my test. As @ryan mentioned I tried 4 ways:

- filling via with solder paste leads to non-conductive vias.
- filling via with solder wire leads to non-conductive vias.
- filling via with copper works fine but is not easy to do as you’ll have to solder both sides and the wire might drop out.
- filling via with copper rivet (unsoldered) gives a some conductive via but has some contact resistance (< 1 ohm).
- Filling via with copper rivet and then solder the rivet both sides is the most trustworthy way to do it with good solid connection.